# How to check if foreground service is running in MAUI

Tags: maui, foreground-service

I want to check if foreground service is already running in MAUI for android then I don't have to do anything but if not running I will start it automatically. I tried Intent.Action but it is always showing me false, even though the foreground service was running as it displays periodic alerts.

Comment: Did you try using/implementing Android.OS.Binder ?

Comment: In Android, I am checking it with ActivityManager, and iterating over all running services, I compare the service class name. Try it, and if it turns out to be too much of a problem to implement it, ask me again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android.OS.Binder for this, which will give you ability to communicate with your service. Bellow, I created a simplified example, how can this be achieved:

Custom service implementing OnBind and OnUnbind:

```
[Service]
public class MyService : Service
{
    private const string _channelId = "123";
    private const int _notifID = 333;
    public bool IsServiceRunning { get; set; }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        IBinder _binder = new ServiceBinder(this);
        StartService();
        return _binder;
    }

    public override bool OnUnbind(Intent intent)
    {
        IsServiceRunning = false;
        return base.OnUnbind(intent);
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    public void StartService()
    {
        Notification notification = CreateNotification();
        StartForeground(_notifID, notification);
        IsServiceRunning = true;
    }

    public Notification CreateNotification()
    {
        Context context = Platform.AppContext;

        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 111, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, _channelId)
            .SetContentTitle("ForegroundService")
            .SetContentText("Message")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.dotnet_bot)
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(_channelId, "Title", NotificationImportance.High);
            notificationChannel.SetShowBadge(true);

            var notificationManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            if (notificationManager != null)
            {
                notificationBuilder.SetChannelId(_channelId);
                notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
        }

        return notificationBuilder.Build();
    }
}
```

Service Connection:

```
public class MyServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
{
    public ServiceBinder Binder { get; set; }

    public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {
        Binder = (ServiceBinder)service;
    }

    public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
    }

    public MyService GetService()
    {
        if (Binder == null)
            return null;

        return Binder.GetService();
    }
}

public class ServiceBinder : Binder
{
    private MyService _service;

    public ServiceBinder(MyService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public MyService GetService()
    {
        return _service;
    }
}
```

ForgroundService for starting service and checking if its running:

```
public class ForegroundService
{
    private readonly MyServiceConnection _serviceConnection;

    public ForegroundService(MyServiceConnection serviceConnection)
    {
        _serviceConnection = serviceConnection;
    }

    public void StartForegroundService()
    {
        Context context = Platform.AppContext;
        Intent intent = new(context, typeof(MyService));
        context.BindService(intent, _serviceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
    }

    public bool IsForegroundServiceRunning()
    {
        if (_serviceConnection.GetService() == null || !_serviceConnection.GetService().IsServiceRunning)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Service can be run and checked in code:

```
MyServiceConnection msc = new MyServiceConnection();
ForegroundService fs = new ForegroundService(msc);
fs.StartForegroundService();
fs.IsForegroundServiceRunning();
```

Comment: Thank you. I just want to check whether the service is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [ActivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningServices(int)) and `GetRunningServices`. Even though it is deprecated there is no other easy way for now.
Note that using this comes with this warning

> Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing
> service management type user interfaces.

Still it is the easiest way to check for your service.

If yo have a Service class called `MyService` you can check it like this

```cs
private bool IsServiceRunning()
{
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService(ActivityService);
    foreach (var service in manager.GetRunningServices(int.MaxValue))
    {
        if (service.Service.ShortClassName.Contains(nameof(MyService)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Recommend to read Alex Coffey going through different method [here](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/java-kotlin-check-if-service-is-running#how-to-determine-if-an-android-service-is-running-in-the-foreground)

Comment: Thank you. I will check and let you know.

Comment: It is throwing the error "'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference'" on the first line i.e. of ActivityManager

Comment: Are you putting this code in MainActivity?